# moving database from file maker pro7 to Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration, filemaker, data-transfer

So I have this fileMakerPro7 database. As my senior project, I supposed to migrate the database to a MySQL database and than give it a PHP Based interface in 3N form...

Company allow us $200 tops to spend on the project, but if I pay for something, it has to work. However, I am having trouble finding a way of migrating the database. Any suggestions?

I have found "file maker pro migrator" (http://www.fmpromigrator.com), would the trial version be enough for us? In worst case, we will start from the beginning with throwing away the whole database that company has.

I can also download fileMakerPro12 and use it for a month with trial version for free. Would I be able to convert the db by using FMP12?

I am totally lost...open to any free suggestions...

+this is a non-profit-making company I'm doing the project for

Comment: is it a requirement the migration is done with a tool of some sort? I'd say your best option is to create the database in mysql and export all the data. FM will let you export the data as csv.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I'd look at the design of the FileMaker db and create something similar in mysql.  Then I would export the Filemaker data to text and import it somehow.  The details depend on foreign key values and such.

The PHP interface would be done separately.

Comment: yeah but I can not find a schema or anything

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL Data Conversion:

Yes, if your database is small enough, the demo version of FmPro Migrator will convert the database and also build you a PHP web application - at no cost.

Here are the limitations of the demo version:

- 5 fields
- 5 scripts
- 5 layouts

### PHP Web Application:

Most people don't realize it, but there is a wealth of FileMaker metadata available in XML format for performing these types of conversions. This XML info is available either thru copying the layout via the clipboard or reading it from the Database Design Report XML file. I have found the clipboard data to be the most reliable source of this info.

FmPro Migrator is able to parse in the XML and convert  it into the PHP web application.

Each object on a layout is represented in XML, along with style and position info. This info can be used to create form files representing the same look as the original layout. In fact, it can be difficult to see the difference between the web application and the original database if you get all of the object properties implemented. This can be helpful for situations in which companies don't want to have to retrain their employees. They want the web application to look and work the same as the original desktop application.

I have done a few of these conversions recently into the CakePHP framework. Here a few techniques I used:

Auto-Enter Calculation Fields - Stored calculation fields are calculated and stored within the model saves a record to the database.

Unstored Calculation Fields - Unstored Calculation fields are calculated in real-time within the form controller - but only for fields actually displayed on the form. This prevents unnecessarily calculating these values if they aren't being used on a form, improving performance.

Global Fields - A Global field in FileMaker is used like a global variable in programming languages. It is important to know that each FileMaker user gets there own private copy of global field data. There is no equivalent feature MySQL or other SQL database servers, but this functionality can easily be simulated using SESSION variables. Therefore each web user will still get their own private SESSION data, simulating the same functionality originally present in the FileMaker database. I structure these globals in the model data array as if they were retrieved from the model, meaning that converted scripts and fields on forms can reference them easily. Just before the record gets written into the database, the results are saved into SESSION variables for persistence.

Global Variables in Scripts - Global variables within FileMaker scripts match up very well with the use of PHP SESSION variables, if you want to implement the same functionality.

Vector Graphic Objects - FileMaker layouts frequently include rectangles, ovals and line objects. These objects can be replaced with the RafaelJS library, providing high quality resolution independent graphics.

Value Lists - Custom and Field based value lists are implemented in a centralized location within the AppController.php file. Therefore making a change to the definition of the value list within the AppController, succeeds in changing the menu automatically throughout the whole application.